# is that any way to Laravel migrate with new database connection using my new Config file?

Tags: laravel, artisan-migrate

without using my config/database.php in **mysql** connection.

to use my config/newdatabase.php in **newsql** connection.

example command such as blow.

```
php artisan migrate database=newsql
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're close, it's `php artisan migrate --database=newsql` but you need to define it as a connection in your `database.php`

Comment: Any other way using my config file connection.

Comment: Not from the command-line no. In code you can do something like `config([ 'database.connections' => array_merge(config('database.connections'), config('newdatabase.connections')) ])` and it should merge the connections defined in each file

Comment: make your own command through artisan?

Comment: You can add this code in a service provider (maybe do a `if (app()->runningInConsole())` first if you only want to restrict it to console commands)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to define a new .env file instead of a second config file with database info. Laravel just won't recognize the second config file, it'll be troublesome.

Create a file called `.env.newsettings`, update your database settings, than run: `php artisan migrate --env=newsettings`